# Can you disable solution files when building with CMake?

Tags: cmake

i am relatively new to cmake, after studying a bit, i saw that cmake is generating a .sln (solution) file for the built code, is there a way to disable this behaviour? If so, which? I wandered in the cmake docs and cmake properties but nothing was found.

The problem is that i already made a .sln file to my project, i just want to add the .vcxproj file to my already made solution, also other projects are in that file, so i would like to have them grouped and organized in one file, so, is it possible?

Comment: I don't use windows, but you can check what generators are available in your cmake installation.  As an aside though, you should probably pick either cmake or your existing build system (the solution you mentioned) and stick with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can try configuring your CMake project into an empty folder and then adding generated projects to your solution.

However, CMake uses the solution file to setup dependencies between targets (which are mapped to projects), including internal targets that invoke CMake under the hood. By skipping running these targets you might get into build system's inconsistent state.

I guess, you will have to just have 2 Visual Studio instances opened - one for the CMake solution and one for your own.

Comment: Ok, i guess i'll have to add the solution to my solution then